# Regex AND'ing

Tags: regex

I have to two strings that I want to match everything that doesn't equal them, the first string can be followed by a number of characters. I tried something like this, negating two ors and negating that result.

```
?!(?!^.*[^Factory]$|?![^AppName])
```

Any ideas?

Comment: to clarify

I want to match anything that

does not end in the word 'Factory' or isn't equal to the word 'AppName'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dfa's answer is by far the best option.  But if you can't use it for some reason, try:

```
^(?!.*Factory|AppName)
```

It's very difficult to determine from your question and your regex what you're trying to do; they seem to imply opposite behaviors.  The regex I wrote will not match if Factory appears anywhere in the string, or AppName appears at the beginning of it.

Answer (score 4):

Try this regular expression:

```
(?!.*Factory$|.*AppName)^.*
```

This matches every string that does not end with `Factory` and does not contain `AppName`.

Answer (score 3):

what about

```
if (!match("(Factory|AppName)")) {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it work if you looked for the existence of those two strings and then negated the regex?